# Magento 2 sales order email not sending

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I am using Magento 2.3.3 here I am facing the issue of sales order email when I place order the order placed successfully but I don't receive any email and in Magento order view it show's email was not sent. But when I trigger manually from the order view page click on send email button then I got the order confirmation email but after placed order from the frontend, I don't get an email I have to manually click on send email button from Magento admin backend for getting email. What may be issue any hint will be appreciatable.

When I checked log I got the below error may it be an issue with email sending :

```
main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId = 'id {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): No such entity with customerId = 'id' at /vendor/magento/framework/Exception/NoSuchEntityException.php:50)"}
```

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

This seems existing magento bug.

Read through this - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23411

its fixed here on dev branch - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23411#issuecomment-554132357

you might wanna apply patch to fix yours - https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/magento/magento2/pull/25307.diff